# Stuck! can only pass data for presentviewcontroller, not pushviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

```
    let chatController = ChatLogController()
    chatController.user = user
    let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatController)
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The code above works, I am trying to pass user, to the next view controller, before presenting
However this doesn't work, it gives me nil for user, in the next viewcontroller:

```
    let chatController = ChatLogController()
    chatController.user = user
   let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MessagesController())
   // self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    nav.pushViewController(chatController, animated: true)
```

I really have no idea why, sorry for the dumb questions, I'm very new to this.

Comment: In your second example, you're instantating a new navigation controller, but that controller is not added to the view controller hierarchy. You have to present it, and only then can you then push anything on it. I also don't quite get why this `MessagesController` is the root view controller of this navigation controller. What is this `MessagesController`? Do you really want to present the navigation controller with both `MessagesController` and `ChatLogController`, or just `ChatLogController`?

Comment: do you want to use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(...)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong your problem is `MessagesController()`.

Try this:

```
let chatController = ChatLogController()
chatController.user = user
let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatController)
// self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
nav.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)
```